# How to redirect input to the Ruby command-line as argument

Tags: ruby, command-line, cmd

I'd like to populate a Ruby script's ARGV with input from the command-line using redirection:

```
ruby myscript.rb < my_cmdline_args.txt
```

This does not seem to work. My script complains that ARGV is empty.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby. Figuring out how to call a program isn't even really a programming question, calling a program is just normal usage of an operating system / shell, and should thus be asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @theTinMan: the question is tagged [tag:cmd], the default shell of OS/2, Windows CE, and Windows NT, so we can safely assume it is one of those three (although really that's irrelevant, since command substitution is a feature of the shell, not the OS).

Answer (score 1):

On your script you can use ARGF to read from the linux pipes, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts ARGF.read
```

try sending a file or some input and it should work, you can do

```
ruby myscript.rb < my_cmdline_args.txt
```

and it will echo the content or

```
cat my_cmdline_args.txt | ruby myscript.rb
```

and it will read the contents the same way

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `xargs`:

```
cat my_cmdline_args.txt | xargs ruby myscript.rb
```

More info: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what you are looking for, since you are both talking about using the contents of a file as arguments, as well as redirection, i.e. using the contents of a file as input.

However, I do believe that something like this is what you want:

```
FOR /F %i IN (my_cmdline_args.txt) DO ruby myscript.rb %i
```